# How do you apply a function to each element of a dataset vector, and then return that vector?

Tags: r, statistics

For context, I have a dataset `v`, and I want to apply `1-exp(-x[i]*theta)` to the i'th element of `v` in succession.

Assume I know the value of theta. I then want to store this as a vector so that I can sort it, and apply it to another function (a 'goodness-of-fit test statistic).

Is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Bernoon. Please read [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R is manipulating vectors so, if `v` is a vector, you can directly pass your equation as follow:

```r
v2 <- 1 - exp(-v*theta)
```

And it will be apply to each element of v and stored it in `v2` object (which will also be a vector).

here an example:

```r
v <- 1:10
theta  = 5

> 1 - exp(-v*theta)

[1] 0.9932621 0.9999546 0.9999997 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

Comment: As it is it is difficult to help, please edit your question and provide a reproducible example of you matrix as described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. Also, please provide the code behind `compute`.